# Custom Feeder in Gatling

Tags: scala, queue, message-queue, gatling, scala-gatling

I want to share some data between 2 simulation and for that I have a designed a custom feeder using queue.

```scala
.exec { session =>
            val writer1 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath, true))
            writer1.write(session("AccountId").as[String] + "," + session("uuid").as[String] + "\n")
            writer1.close();
            session
          }
          .exec {
            session =>
            DequeHolder.DataDeque.offer(Array(session("AccountId").as[String][0],session("uuid").as[String][1]))
            session
          }
      }
  }

  class DataFeeder extends Feeder[String] {
    override def hasNext: Boolean = DequeHolder.DataDeque.size() > 0
    override def next(): Map[String, Array[String]] = Map("data" -> DequeHolder.DataDeque.poll())
  }
```

this is giving me compilation issue at line `DequeHolder.DataDeque.offer(Array(session("AccountId").as[String][0],session("uuid").as[String][1]))`

Could someone please help where exactly I am commiting mistake.

> Error: io.gatling.commons.util.TypeCaster[String], evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[String], evidence$3: io.gatling.commons.NotNothing[String]): String does not take type parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Feeder[T]` is an alias for `Iterator[Map[String, T]]`.

So `override def next(): Map[String, Array[String]]` is wrong for `Feeder[String]`.

Comment: thanks .Any idea what I need to change to make it right ?